# Discontinuous function on the sphere

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

In $\mathbb{R}^n$ endowed with the euclidean norm , Let $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ be the unit sphere

we consider the function $f :\mathbb{S}^{n-1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ not necessairly contiunous such that :

for each $u\in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$,  $f(u)< +\infty $

Can we deduce that $f$  is bounded  ? ( i.e $Sup_{u\in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}}(f(u))<\infty$)

I know if $f$ is contiuous this is true (Extreme value theorem)

but what if $f$ is not continuos ?

Comment: Why did you add that you always have $f(u)<+\infty$? Since $f$ is a map from $S^{n-1}$ into $\Bbb R_+$, that's automatically true, right?!

Comment: yes, your are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a counter example consider any fixed point $s \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ and define

$$f(u):=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{||u-s||} & \text{for $u\neq s$} \\ 0 & \text{for $u=s$}\end{cases}.$$

Comment: well, this is  obvious . Thanks @Leander Tilsted Kristensen

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly false as written. Take any bijection from $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. If you'd like to make it continuous almost everywhere, distinguish one point $\ast$ on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. Then $\mathbb{S}^{n-1} \setminus \{\ast\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, and define your $f$ to one of those homeomorphisms away from $\ast$, and $f(\ast) = 0$.

Comment: thanks @user3482749   +1